# Why behavior is different of render() vs render("some template.html")

Tags: playframework, render, playframework-1.x

I just started to learn Play 1.x that is required by my company and I go through the Play tutorial to create a blog engine in this part: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/guide4

```
public static void show(Long id) {
    Post post = Post.findById(id);
    render(post);
}

public static void postComment(Long postId, @Required String author, @Required String content) {
    Post post = Post.findById(postId);
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        render("Application/show.html", post); // why not show(post.postId) ?
    }
    post.addComment(author, content);
    show(postId);
}
```

Why  they suggest to render template by providing it name as a string `render("Application/show.html", post);` in case of validation error? Why not just to run `show(post.postId)` controller that looks to do the same?

It seems template catch validation errors only if executed as render("Application/show.html", post); and if executed as `show(post.postId)` validation errors are not visible to template.

Answer (score 0):

The validation errors happened in the `postComment` method. Invoking `show(post.postId)` effectively triggers a HTTP redirect and therefor the validation errors would get lost (because the server is stateless).